# rdlc - Concatenate 2 tablix - same dataset - synchronization lost..,

Tags: c#, sql-server, pdf, rdlc

Since i haven't find a way to merge colunms cells in rdlc, I've tried to concatenate 2 tablixes horizontaly- one is "standard" table, and the other is one field (those were my needs).
Running my sp on my rdlc, it works fine where there is one record to display.
However, when the result is multiple records, and I'm saving results in .pdf file, the 2 tables are not "synchronized" together any more - the gaps between results of each records are different.
I've tried to surrender the tablixes in rectangle and define a page break after rectangle - table still not synchronized...
Please advice..... ☺

Comment: I cannot picture what you are describing.   Can you upload some screenshots?

Comment: In other words: I define 2 tablixes in same rdlc, one horizontally near the other. My stored procedure returns several records and supposed to display data of each record in those 2 tables (which should be in the same horizontal line as I've defined them in the designer.

Comment: I got that, but I don't know what you mean by the tables not being synchronized?

Comment: That means, not being "concatenated horizontally" as I've put them in the designer. They are displayed in the same line only for the first record, but not for the next ones.

Comment: Well that can happen if the line height of your data isn't exactly the same.   If you want the rows to always line up horizontally, then you have to combine your two tablix into one.

Answer (score 0):

Combine your two tablix into one.   You can create the appearance of having two by putting an empty column between the two "sides" with no borders on top or bottom of the cells.  It will look like two tables side by side, even though it is one table, and the rows will be forced to line up horizontally.

Comment: As far as I underdtand,I cannot put all data in the same table, because one of the tables has several rows (the data in it belongs to same record, but it is displayed in several rows) and the other table contains one field only (should contain image, with height different from the height of the other table). It seems to me that I'll try to define both tablix in same height, and try to display the image in absolute size.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility for you is to have a sub-report.  Create a simple report of just the tablix of the second table in question of the field(s) you want to include.

Then edit your primary report to include the sub-report.  I cant direct in detail now how to link-up the sub reports and parameter link them, but suggest some reading up on it.  So Each detail row in the parent report would be a group by (its PKID for example), then add the sub-report to it.  This way as many rows at the sub-level go if 1 or more...